# How to test functions which do not return anything using QTestLib

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qtestlib

I am new to unit testing and QTestLib. I  could not find the answer to this particular problem. How do I test functions (or units) that do not return anything. I have read the tutorials given in the Qt site, but I do not know how to proceed.

I have reproduced the [TextFinder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-textfinder-example.html) example given in the Qt website. I now want to test the function on_findbutton_clicked. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience of using QTestLib, But according to the experience I use other unit test framework, you can not test function which do not return anything with [**black box testing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). Occasionally, if it change the global variable, then you can check the global variable outside of those function to test it, otherwise, you should modify that function and set check point in it to test.